# Implementing NSSortDescriptor in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I have an nsmutablearray named nsmarrMedicineInfo. I want to sort the element by using `NSSortDescriptor`. When I execute the following code it shows `NSUnknownKeyException`. I can not find what will be the key of the array.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sort" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray *sort = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [nsmarrMedicineInfo sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sort];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here key will be one of the ***property(key-value pair) of your custom object*** of array `nsmarrMedicineInfo`, on which you wish to sort your array.
As in apple's doc:

> An instance of NSSortDescriptor describes a basis for ordering objects
>   by specifying the property to use to compare the objects, the method
>   to use to **compare the properties**, and whether the comparison should be
>   ascending or descending.

But if `nsmarrMedicinInfo` object consists of strings only then you can use `sortedArrayUsingSelector` method instead of `sortDescriptor`.

Thanks,